# Swift Problem with the restore of non cosumable app purchase

Tags: ios, swift

I made a non consumable purchase in my app, but I've got a problem with the purchase. When in my simulator it works good, but when I try the purchase in my device I get this error:

> Ignoring restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername: because already restoring transactions

I found some other questions here, but I can not resolve the problem anyway

That's my code:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions {        

   case SKPaymentTransactionState.restored:

            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

            RestoreButton.isEnabled = true
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            productTitle.text = "Thank you"
            productDescription.text = "The product has been purchased"
            buyButton.isEnabled = false

            let save = UserDefaults.standard
            save.set(true, forKey: "Purchase")
            save.synchronize()

        case SKPaymentTransactionState.failed:

            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            productTitle.text = "Warning"
            productDescription.text = "The product has not been purchased"

        default:
            break

        }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you initiate the restore?  Also, you should ensure that you have updated the purchase state (the user defaults bit) before calling `finishTransaction`. And there is no need to call `synchronize`,  but these won't cause your problem

Comment: Okay i edited the code up....I'm missing something?